# Update my content into XML-file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I just gratefully managed to load the content of an XML-file into my php-document, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "abstimmer.xml", 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: function (xml) { 
            var $lis = $(".abstimmer li");
            $(xml).find('klick').each(function (index) {
                if (index < $lis.length) {
                    $lis.eq(index).html($(this).text());
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
```

By that, the content of these nodes get pushed into the li-elements of the parental ul-element identifiable with class "abstimmer".

I now want to also push data from the php-file back into the xml-file.
I'd like to do this by counting the clicks on a li-element, what I do in that manner:

```
$(".abstimmer li").click(function(){
    this.clicked=this.clicked?this.clicked+1:1;
$(this).html(this.clicked)
var klick_neu = $(this).html(this.clicked);
// Where would I need to go from here?
});
```

I know, that I now need to send var klick_neu to a php-file that somehow parses the var klick_neu and pushes it into that xml-file. But I have no clue how to do that. Could somebody help me with that?

And I am not sure, if that's alright with stackoverflows' rules, but I am just curious on an additional thing within the same problem: If I just added an onClick-Event within the ready-function, I could "seamlessly" load the updated content of the xml-file into my list - right?

Thanks a lot.

My XML-file will more or less, look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abstimmer>
<seite id="2">
    <klick>3</klick>
    <klick>5</klick>
    <klick>9</klick>
    <klick>12</klick>
    <klick>1</klick>
    <klick>0</klick>
</seite>
```

Comment: Well if you want the value to be updated in the xml, the serverside code would need to update the file.

Comment: PHP has a x(ht)ml parser called `DOM:DOCUMENT`. It can open xml files and put new content into it.

Comment: Thanks for your updates. How would I do that in particular? a) How can I call that php-file that generates the action within the query-block?
b) Could you guide me a bit on what the php-file should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach I wrote. You'll need to adept it. I don't really know the mark up of your xml document. I extrapolated from the code you submitted. What this does. Whenever somebody clicks upon a `LI` an AJAX call is made to the server. There the xml is updated and posted back in the response. The HTML in the page gets updated with the new data. One drawback of this method is that it only supports one action a time. If two persons would write into the same file it would result in data loss. A better solution would be to keep track of this using a database.

```
$(".abstimmer li").click(function(){
    var klick_neu = parseInt($(this).html())+1;
    var index = Array.prototype.slice.call($(".abstimmer li")).indexOf(this);

    //create an ajax call that posts the new click count to the server.
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "abstimmer.php", 
        dataType : "xml",
        data : {clicks : klick_neu, element : index},
        success: function (data) { 
            var $lis = $(".abstimmer li");
            $(data).find('klick').each(function (index) {
                if (index < $lis.length) {
                    $lis.eq(index).html($(this).text());
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

The new **abstimmer.php** file

```
<?php
    $clicks = $_POST['clicks'];
    $index = $_POST['element'];
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load("abstimmer.xml");

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("klick");
    $elements->item($index)->nodeValue = $clicks;

    $xml = $doc->saveXML();

    if($handle = fopen("abstimmer.xml", "w"))
    {
        if (!fwrite($handle, $xml))
        {
            fclose($handle);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    echo $xml;

?>
```

Comment: Wow! that's way more then I expected. Awesome. My developing skills are obviously a bit .... I did adapt the js-source to point to the correct path of the but nothing else (as your variable names are the same ones I use). Though something is done wrong by me - neither do I get the xml-content into the file, nor does the updated of the values get pushed back into the xml. What would I need to check for / how to make it running? Thanks again!

Comment: I really feel a bit ashamed, but not yet working. You may check the actual page? http://der-shopstart.de/welche-produkte-kommen-in-frage-kickoff#abstimmzahl

Comment: Too much javascript lately too little PHP :-). Made a booboo. Corrected it in the PHP code. Please try again :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69152/discussion-between-mouser-and-daiaiai).

Comment: So glad this finally worked! Awesome. Though I get an initial delay at the very beginning, but that's a different question. Thanks!